# PostgreSQL Function not executing in Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to execute a PostgreSQL Function which is used to insert rows into a table.

I have used sqlalchemy to connect with the database.

When I execute the below code, there is no error, but nothing happens.

```
insertrows= text("""select public.insertrows1(1, :file_name, 1, 'FtpLoaded', '2022-04-08', 0, 0, 0, '2022-03-08 19:34:47.255962', '2022-03-08 19:34:47.255962', 1, '')""")

conn.execute(insertrows, file_name =s )
```

The SELECT and UPDATE statements work just fine, but I do not know why this does not work.

If I print(insertrows) and copy the result and run it in pgAdmin, 4 the Function executes and I can see the new rows.

Comment: To persist the changes you need to add a `conn.commit()` after the `conn.execute()`. See [Connection](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html), in particular the *commit()* section.

Comment: See also [Working with Engines and Connections](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#module-sqlalchemy.engine), in particular  [Using transactions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#using-transactions)

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver! After Commit, I was able to see the changes.